# How to execute a batch file across several disk drives

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

```
Set DriveList= "C: D: E:"
for %%A in (%DriveList%) Do (
    Dir %%A*.txt
    Dir %%A*.jpg
)
pause
```

This returns a listing of the first directory in the list - without any files, then does not move to the next drive letter in the list (D:). What is needed is to perform the Dir commands for drives c,d and e, and list any txt or jpg files in them.

Comment: Oh man, you're gonna kick yourself. You're looping over the drive letters and setting `%%A` to each letter, but you aren't using it in your code anywhere.

Comment: How and where would you place the calls to %DriveList% and/or %%A in the script to make it iterate through the drive letters? Appreciate the help. Thanks much.

Comment: `%%A\*.txt`, etc.

Comment: I have revised the code above in the question along with how it performs. Sill unresolved...

Comment: Yeah, because you forgot the \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did get loads of help in the comments section, but anyhow, here is how:

```
@echo off
Set "DriveList=C:\ D:\ E:\"
for %%i in (%DriveList%) Do (
  dir /b /a-d %%i*.txt
  dir /b /a-d %%i*.jpg
)
pause
```

Note that the above will only search the root of each drive, to search for ALL files on each drive, you need to include the `/S` switch:

```
@echo off
Set "DriveList=C:\ D:\ E:\"
for %%i in (%DriveList%) Do (
  dir /b /a-d /s %%i*.txt
  dir /b /a-d /s %%i*.jpg
)
pause
```

I suggest you read the help by opening cmd.exe and typing:

```
set /?
for /?
dir /?
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative:

```bat
@For %%A In (C: D: E:) Do @Where /R %%A *.txt *.jpg 2>Nul
```